# Please can I know why I keep getting this OSError?

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-settings

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ''

Comment: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:`. Provide what you have, which gives this error, and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).